# How to make an entire StackedColumn clickable, not just the DataPoints in it

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, charts, stacked

It's not easy to click on a Chart column when the data point values are small in relation to the max value in the Chart because the clickable area is so small.  So, I'd like to find a way to make entire columns clickable, including the blank areas above and below the displayed data points.

I've been looking into doing that with Striplines that align with the columns since Striplines are detected by HitTest, but am struggling to understand if/how it's possible to do the alignment.

Is that a feasible idea or is there some other way to meet my objective?

Screenshot shows the problem.  The data in 2025 is highlighted with BackHatching.

[image: Screenshot shows the problem. The data in 2025 is highlighted with BackHatching.]

Comment: Could you tag this with the technologies you're using

Comment: Yeah.  I should have done that upfront.  It's a C# WinForms app developed with Visual Studio Community 2015 on a Win 8.1 laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
private void chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    int zeroPix = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(0);
    HitTestResult hittr = chart1.HitTest(e.X, zeroPix );

    // now you can do your stuff..    
    Text = hittr.ChartElementType.ToString();
}
```

The trick is to test not the actual vertical mouse location but the pixel where the data value of `zero` sits. Since a (correctly filled) `StackedColumn` chart should have a `DataPoint` at this spot for all columns we can do the `HitTest` there.

The same trick should also work for a Column chart: Here too each column will go up or down to its y-value but always start at 0.

The idea to use `StripLines` is intriguing, btw, but I can't think of a way  of finding the right widths and positions.

Another alternative would be to scan over all points in all series to find the ones we are closest and then use their values, but this sounds even more expensive..

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks.  For others who may read this, you get the X Axis value that was clicked (the Year in my case) by Rounding  hittr.Axis.PixelPositionToValue(e.X).  Note that you may need to test for X Axis values that are outside the charted range since clicking in front of the 1st column or after the last one will return an uncharted X Axis value.

Comment: I just discovered that my suggestion for getting the X Axis value doesn't work when there are negative values because the hittr.Axis value is null for some reason.  So, replace my statement above by Rounding chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X) instead.